Maxent linear features
I am using Maxent to analyze the habitat of a species and I am setting the model to linear features. If I understand correctly, Maxent uses environmental variables as "linear features," meaning that in the model, the relationships between the environmental variables and the probability of species presence are considered linear relationships. In other words, it assumes that each environmental variable influences the probability of presence directly and proportionally, without complex or nonlinear interactions between the variables.
Is that correct?
